# Convert Base64 encoded String into Image file back on Java Server

Tags: android, string, image, base64

I want to send Image from Android to Server. I decoded image into Base64 String and send it to the server. I use following code to convert Image to String

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);  
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);  
    byte [] byteArray = bao.toByteArray();  
    String imageToString=Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);  
    return imageToString;
```

Now i am unable to convert it back to Image on server side. I tried this

```
   byte[] imageBytes=Base64.decode(imageString);  
   InputStream in =  new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);  
   BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);  
   ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", new File("D:\\myImage.jpg"));
```

i am getting **Bogus Huffman table definition** exception and sometime **im = null** exception. plz tell me what mistake i am making

Edit: Error Message **javax.imageio.IIOException: Bogus Huffman table definition** at this line

```
  BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Comment: mistake a) you did not post the error message. b) check if you can save the `Base64.decode()` output as a file and open it with any image viewer / compare to your original data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
        byte[] imageBytes=Base64.decode(imageString,Base64.NO_WRAP);
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there might be multiple issues here. The first one I think is the fact that you convert the image bytes to String (encoding them with whatever default encoding you Android environment has) and the decoding that String back to bytes without ensuring that you use the same text encoding (and thus get the same bytes).

Why not send the bytes directly? Or better yet just upload the file directly via HTTP multi-part form. There's a tutorial on this here:

http://flo.dauran.com/194-android-uploader-une-image-sur-une-serveur-web/

(it's in french, but there's detailed code examples)